# How to sort by match prioritising the most left words matched

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch, prefix

How to sort by match prioritising the most left words matched

## Explanation

Sort the prefix query by the word it matches, but prioritising the matches in the words more at left.

## Tests I've made

### Data

```
DELETE /test
PUT /test

PUT /test/person/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "original": {
          "type": "string", 
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/person/1
{"name": "Berta Kassulke"}

PUT /test/person/2
{"name": "Kaley Bartoletti"}

PUT /test/person/3
{"name": "Kali Hahn"}

PUT /test/person/4
{"name": "Karolann Klein"}

PUT /test/person/5
{"name": "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"}
```

> The mapping was added for the 'sort on original value' test.

### Simple query

#### Query

```
POST /test/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {"name": {"value": "ka"}}
  }
}
```

#### Result

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Karolann Klein"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Berta Kassulke"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kaley Bartoletti"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kali Hahn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### With sorting

#### Request

```
POST /test/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {"name": {"value": "ka"}}
  },
  "sort": {"name": {"order": "asc"}}
}
```

#### Result

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kaley Bartoletti"
        },
        "sort": [
          "bartoletti"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Berta Kassulke"
        },
        "sort": [
          "berta"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kali Hahn"
        },
        "sort": [
          "hahn"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
           "name": "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"
        },
        "sort": [
          "kaloo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Karolann Klein"
        },
        "sort": [
          "karolann"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### With sort on original value

#### Query

```
POST /test/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {"name": {"value": "ka"}}
  },
  "sort": {"name.original": {"order": "asc"}}
}
```

#### Result

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Berta Kassulke"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Berta Kassulke"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kaley Bartoletti"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Kaley Bartoletti"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Kali Hahn"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Kali Hahn"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Karolann Klein"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Karolann Klein"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "person",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
           "name": "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"
        },
        "sort": [
          "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Intended result

Sorted by name ASC but prioritising the matches on the most left words

1. Kaley Bartoletti
2. Kali Hahn
3. Karolann Klein
4. Berta Kassulke
5. Sofia Mandez Kaloo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question. One way to achieve this would be with the combination of [edge ngram filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html?q=edge) and [span first query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-first-query.html)

This is my setting

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_custom_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase",
                        "edge_filter",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "edge_filter": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 8
                }

            }

        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard",
                    "fields": {
                        "standard": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After that I inserted your sample documents. Then I wrote the following query with [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html). Notice that **`end`** parameter for first `span query` is 1 so this will **prioritize(higher score)** leftmost match. I am first sorting by `score` and then by `name`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "tie_breaker": 0.7,
      "boost": 1.2,
      "queries": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "ka"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_term": {
                "name": "ka"
              }
            },
            "end": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_term": {
                "name": "ka"
              }
            },
            "end": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "name.standard": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result I get

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "esedge",
            "_type": "policy_data",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.72272325,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Kaley Bartoletti"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.72272325,
               "bartoletti"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "esedge",
            "_type": "policy_data",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.72272325,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Kali Hahn"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.72272325,
               "hahn"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "esedge",
            "_type": "policy_data",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.72272325,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Karolann Klein"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.72272325,
               "karolann"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "esedge",
            "_type": "policy_data",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.54295504,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Berta Kassulke"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.54295504,
               "berta"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "esedge",
            "_type": "policy_data",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.2905494,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Sofia Mandez Kaloo"
            },
            "sort": [
               0.2905494,
               "kaloo"
            ]
         }
      ]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was expecting something simpler XD But this worked.

Comment: I tried and added the name "Gil Cesar Raff Kaloo", then the sort got crazy and sent the Berta to first place, and Gil to second last. any idea why, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: span query is `not analyzed` so _Ka_ is different than _ka_, you have to take care of that, since your name is of 4 words, you might have to add one more `span query` with `end parameter` 3. I assumed names wont be more than 3 words long, but I guess i was wrong

Comment: what is the max length in terms of number of words your name field is going to be?

Comment: there is none :( it will be names, of persons, can be like Pablo Picasso which has 14 names